# Remove start and end of a string

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have the following string:

> wassup=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;domain=.asdf.com;path=/;secure;httponly;

I need to remove the beginning of the string "wassup=" which can be done with **substr(7, str.length)** and the end of the string ";domain=.asdf.com;path=/;secure;httponly;"

To remove the end I was trying with indexOf(";") but this only removed part of what I needed.

I would like a simple way of doing this to keep the code as clean as possible (all done in one line/attempt).

Comment: Why am i being downvoted? I would like feedback of those downvotes to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and clean is tough with these kind of problems, but assuming the `=` at the beginning of the string and the `;` at the end of the string you can achieve one line with this:

```
str.split('=')[1].split(';')[0]
```

This will throw errors if your result has no `=`, and also if there's more than one `=` it is likely going to give you the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.substring(7, str.indexOf(';'));
```

or even better

```
str.substring(str.indexOf('='), str.indexOf(';'));
```

Comment: That would only remove the last part but not the beginning.